# Proper output of php array into html code

Tags: php, html, output

I have this piece of code where I need to output some `$_POST` values into HTML. Nothing happens in the output line (see comment inside the code), even though `var_dump()` shows that the needed values are in the array and under the desired indexes.

The trick is that the array indexes for the required data depend on the counter `$i`. I'm feeling like there is some really stupid and basic syntax mistake in this code. Please help me, oh almighty Hivemind!

```
while ($i < $somespecificvar) 
{ 
    if (($i != 0) AND ($i < $somespecificvar)) 
    {
        echo "\n<td></td>\n";
    }

    echo "<td>";

    if ($_POST["text_l$i"] != 0)
    {
        echo "{$_POST['text_l$i']}, {$_POST['l$i']}";// NOTHING HAPPENS OVER HERE
    }

    echo "</td>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you can use the `{$variable}` inside a "" string, however it can only really handle basic variables. Change it so it's like so:

```
echo $_POST['text_l' . $i] . ', ' . $_POST['l' . $i];
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, man! I've spent days on trying to fix this one!